# Error when adding int elements from a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I have this code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> test_vector;
    std::vector<int>::iterator v;
    int test = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        test = test * 2;
        test_vector.push_back(test);
    }

    for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); v++) {
        std::cout << *v << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse(test_vector.begin(), test_vector.end());

    for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); v++) {
        std::cout << *v << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); ++v) {
        sum = sum + test_vector[*v];
        std::cout << sum << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's quite easy, I have a vector, fill it with some elements, than going reverse and finally trying to add all the elements.

The output is this:

```
2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 
1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 68 324
```

The question is this: What am I doing wrong in the last loop where the `sum` is ?

I'd like it to be something like `1024 + 512 + 256` etc;

Comment: `test_vector[*iterator];` is a big code smell

Comment: what you have is UB, you should have `sum = sum + *v;` instead of `sum = sum + test_vector[*v];`

Comment: An iterator is not an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector has only 10 elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                ^^^^^^
    test = test * 2;
    test_vector.push_back(test);
}
```

So the valid range of indices for the vector is `0-9`

However in this loop

```
for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); ++v) {
    sum = sum + test_vector[*v];
                           ^^^^^
    std::cout << sum << " ";
}
```

the value of the index in this expression `test_vector[*v]` can be outside the valid range of indices for the vector.

You could write for example

```
for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); ++v) {
    sum = sum + *v;
                ^^^^
    std::cout << sum << " ";
}
```

Or you could even write

```
for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); ++v) {
    sum = sum + v[0];
                ^^^^
    std::cout << sum << " ";
}
```

If your compiler supports the range based for loop then it is simpler to write

```
for ( int x : test_vector ) {
    sum = sum + x;
    std::cout << sum << " ";
}
```

Take into account that operators < and [] are supported only for random access iterators. So in general it is better to write the condition in for loop the following way

```
for (v = test_vector.begin(); v != test_vector.end(); ++v) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `v[0]` aka `iterator[index]` is questionable (not working if the iterator id no pointer)

Comment: @DieterLücking  This operator works with any random access iterator.

Comment: Thanks for that lesson (is it useful?)

Comment: @DieterLücking I never see it myself.:) I mentioned it only regarding with this question.:)

Comment: @DieterLücking Till now I have written neither C++ program because I am unemployed.:)

Comment: No `std::accumulate` option makes me a sad C++ enthusiast.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); ++v) {
        sum = sum + *v;
        std::cout << sum << " ";
}
```

is the correct code.

Or, the same but a bit shorter and more C++11-ish:

```
for (const int item: test_vector) {
    sum += item;
    std::cout << sum << " ";
}
```

Or even

```
sum = std::accumulate(test_vector.begin(), test_vector.end(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `test_vector[*v];` will be out of range and cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This should be changed to:

```
for (v = test_vector.begin(); v < test_vector.end(); ++v) {
    sum = sum + *v;
    std::cout << sum << " ";
}
```

Or `sum += *v;` for a shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `test_vector[*v]` is incorrect. What you are doing there is you are dereferencing an iterator and get an integer (since your vector is a vector of ints). Now, you access an element using this integer as index and of course, arrive at random memory location, going out of array bounds and triggering undefined behaviour.

You are using iterators correctly in two other loops, so i assume, this is just a typo.